# Intellij 14 e Plugin Scala. Erro ao localizar métodos padrão

Tags: ide, scala, intellij-idea

Atualizei meu Intellij IDEA para versão 14 e agora ele não está reconhecendo mais alguns métodos dentro do meu programa Scala.

A IDE não encontra nem o mais simples dos métodos:

```
println("Hello world")
```

O que fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Existe um bug nesta versão, como relatado [aqui](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7764) e [aqui](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7734).

Uma possível solução é invalidar os caches dentro da IDE em:

```
File > Invalidate Caches
```